# FloatImage in Dash Leaflet

Tags: python, leaflet, plotly-dash, folium, dash-leaflet

So I have been working with folium and dash-leaflet for a little bit and I have been seeing some differences in how you create maps between the two packages. One of the things that I have found in folium that is nice is an object called a [FloatImage](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/FloatImage.ipynb) where you can have an image "float" on the screen so that it stays the same size in the same place whenever you pan or zoom in on the map. I would like to have something similar in dash-leaflet, however, I have not found anything with an example for this. I had looked at the [documentation](https://dash-leaflet.herokuapp.com/) where there are many different examples with dash-leaflet, but none of them include a FloatImage like object. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent of the `FloatImage` construct from Folium in `dash-leaflet`. However, you can achieve an image floating on top of the map with a few standard html elements. Here is a small example,

```
from dash import Dash, html
import dash_leaflet as dl

image_url = "https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Tao-Chen-87/publication/3935609/figure/fig1/AS:394647298953219@1471102656485/8-bit-256-x-256-Grayscale-Lena-Image.png"
app = Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dl.Map(dl.TileLayer(), style={'width': '100%', 'height': '100%'}),
    html.Img(src=image_url, style={'position': 'absolute', 'top': 20, 'right': 20, 'zIndex': 1000})
], style={'width': '1000px', 'height': '500px', 'position': 'relative'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for! I'm surprised that the regular html component works in the map like that, but I guess whatever works. Thank you!