# Setting a Maximum Size on Circle Markers

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, folium, dash-leaflet

What I am trying to achieve is have a circle marker where the size changes when you zoom in or out, but I want to set a maximum size they can get (instead of just continuing to get bigger). Is there a way to do this using dash-leaflet? From what I have found on the internet, your two options are to either have the circle marker size be constant or always dynamic. The problem with setting the size as a constant is that once you have zoomed in far enough, the marker blocks other things on the map. But at the same time when I zoom way out I don't want the marker covering everything either. I know there are layers where you can use z-indices, but that is not what I am after. In the case of what I am doing, I would like the marker to get smaller as I zoom in, but only get bigger to a certain size (say 20 miles) zooming out. If anyone knows how to do this, it would be greatly appreciate to show a simple example of a circle marker doing this.

Thanks

**Update**

For reference, here is a simple example of what I am talking about

```
import dash_leaflet as dl
from dash import Dash, html

app = Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(
                    children=[
                        dl.Map(center=[39, -98], zoom=4, children=[
                            dl.TileLayer(),
                            dl.Circle(
                                center=[40.7128, -74.0060],
                                radius=9000, color='black', 
                                opacity=1, 
                                fillOpacity=1),
                            dl.CircleMarker(
                                center=[39.9526, -75.1652],
                                color='white', 
                                opacity=1, 
                                fillOpacity=1)],
                            style={'width': '100%', 'height': '100vh'})])
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

When you first open the application, you can see this

[image]

The circle marker is bigger than the circle, and I want the circle marker to be the size of the circle at its maximum.

When you zoom in, then you see this
[image]

Now you have the issue where the circle is too big and it should get smaller to be what the circle marker shows. So ideally I want the combination of the two where once you have zoomed far enough out that the circle marker doesn't get any bigger, but when I zoom in it should adjust in size accordingly like the circle marker.

Answer (score 0):

By injecting javascript you can have a function that sets marker size based on zoom.   Have used a simple ternary operator.  This could be far more sophisticated to calculate radius in pixels based on distance.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import folium
import numpy as np

geo_df = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"))
geo_df["pop"] = np.random.randint(1, 5, len(geo_df))

m = geo_df.explore(
    column="pop",
    cmap="summer",
    height=300,
    width=500,
)

# inject html into the map html to make circle markers responsive
m.get_root().html.add_child(
    folium.Element(
        """
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    var updateIconSizes = function(){
        var z = {mapObj}.getZoom();
        {mapObj}.eachLayer(function (layer) {
            if ("setRadius" in layer) {
                layer.setRadius(z<3 ? 2*z : 2+z**2);
            }; 
        });
    }
    updateIconSizes();
    {mapObj}.on("zoomend", updateIconSizes);
}
</script>
""".replace(
            "{mapObj}", m.get_name()
        )
    )
)

m
```

Comment: This is the general idea that I am looking for, but do you know how to achieve this in dash-leaflet? One of the things that drives me a little crazy is that even though dash-leaflet and folium both use leaflet, the approach to achieving things can be different enough that I would not even have realized how to do it [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72998226/floatimage-in-dash-leaflet](example). Would it be that you would have that javascript in the options of the dash-leaflet Circle as an assign? What would that javascript be?

Comment: the javascript is for leaflet,  so as long as you inject it appropriately I would expect it works with dash-leaflet as well.   you've not provided a MWE so it's not possible to know what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I have gone ahead and added an example to illustrate what I am meaning. I am sorry that I have been nebulous with things.